# Why the code below is giving this output?

Tags: c

[I want to write a code for printing a rhombus of stars in c Language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpyeC.jpg)
I have written a code that gives the desired output. :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, i, j, K;
    printf("Enter no. of rows; ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n - i + 1; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But, I want to get the same result another way. So, I wrote the another code expecting the same result which is below.

I tried this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, a, i, j;
    printf("Enter no. of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = n - i + 1; 2 * n - i >= j > n - i; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[I was expecting the desired output which came for the code written above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EiQ5.jpg)
[But, it resulted in this output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O71Po.jpg)
So, I am confused. Why did this happen?
Please explain.

Comment: The second code doesn't print any spaces, how do you expect it to print the same thing?

Comment: If you have some simple code that works, you are done. Trying to write some more complicated, harder to read, code is not a goal. (Unless you compete in The International Obfuscated C Code Contest https://www.ioccc.org/).

Comment: what do you expect from `2 * n - i >= j > n - i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test expression in the inner for loop is not in the correct format.
Mathematically correct but yields undesired results in c.

It should be:

```
for (int j = n - i + 1; 2 * n - i >= j && j > n - i; j++)
```

The reason is that boolean operators have arity of 2 and are evaluated left to right.

How your code is actually evaluated is this `(2 * n - i >= j) > n - i`

So you first evaluate `(2 * n - i >= j)` which becomes 1 (True), then you evaluate `1 > n - i`

That is why you see `*****` only on i=5 row.

(You still have a problem that your asterisks are not properly indented, for that you need to print spaces infront.)